# Problems deploying Silverlight PivotViewer

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I have a Silverlight PivotViewer application that is working perfectly in Visual Studio.  My problems occur when I try to deploy the application.  The application starts as usual with a "Loading" animation and the path to the CXML file in the upper left.  The problem is when the Loading animation is finished, it simply disappears and nothing else appears on the screen.  Only the path to the CXML file remains in the upper left.

I have done the following:

1. Ensure that all files are in the same location on the server to in order to avoid any cross-domain issues
2. Added a clientaccesspolicy.xml to the root
3. Ensure that the path to the CXML file exists on the server
4. Add the following MIME Types:

   - .cxml - text/xml
   - .dzc - text/xml
   - .dzi - text/xml

Nothing seems to help.  Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Have you checked that the silverlight app isn't throwing any unhandled exceptions?

Comment: I´m have this issue too. The application runs in VS2010, but not on the server. I´m using Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.0. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? I have the same problem, runs fin on local machine with IIS Express, but when publish to Server when hit page it just shows never ending loading spinning animation.

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler to the Loading Fail event and look at the exception?

```
         PivotViewer.CollectionLoadingFailed += new EventHandler< CollectionErrorEventArgs >( PivotViewer_CollectionLoadingFailed );
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird, I suggest you to do the following:

- Try to access the CXML Link using your web browser ( to check the link is broken or not)
- Did you try to open your pivot CXML with Pivot Desktop Viewer?

Maybe the CXML is not a Valid XML file, you can check it if it's valid or not by saving the cxml file.. rename it to .xml drag drop it over a Firefox window.  If you get Yellow Screen that means the XML file is not well formed and you'll get the error details.

Hope that helps you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the CXML file from Desktop Pivot Viewer, try using this tool http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewcox/archive/2010/07/14/a-tool-to-help-diagnose-problems-setting-up-your-pivotviewer-app.aspx